# Trying to make Plotly Graphs responsive in React application

Tags: reactjs, plotly.js

I am trying to make a Plot component from Plotly.js responsive to the screen size. I am importing it as from a Flask Api. No matter what I try, I cannot the graph to be responsive. The following is what I have for the Plot component ( I am using a function component):

```
<Plot
     data={fig.data}
     config={{
       displaylogo: false,
       responsive: true,
     }}
     layout={{
       ...fig.layout,
       autosize: true,
     }}
     useResizeHandler
     style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%" }}
   />
 </div>
```